# Moving only up and right along the line segments, how many paths are there from A to B?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

[image: Question]

I know the total number of paths is 3432.  I have tried splitting the shape into smaller shapes and I am not having any success.  In addition, I have tried labeling the paths below and I am not sure where I went wrong.  Any help is great help:)

[image: Work]

Comment: In your hand calculation, you put the empty shape in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I realized this right after I posted.  Thank you, again!

Answer (score 2):

Let the vertices be labeled starting from $(0,0)$ to $(7,7)$.  That makes the missing vertices $(3,3)$ and $(4,4)$.

Your mistake was, as pointed out in the comments by @TodorMarkov, that you incorrectly had the missing vertices as $(3,2)$ and $(4,3)$ instead which throws off the numbers, but that being said even that doesn't explain the proposed answer of 3432.

For an analytical approach which avoids brute force, consider counting the opposite... paths which go through at least one of $(3,3),(4,4)$, and do this by way of inclusion-exclusion.

Let $A$ be the event we pass through $(3,3)$, $B$ the event that we pass through $(4,4)$, and $C$ that we pass through $(5,5)$.

$|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$

To go from $(0,0)$ to $(7,7)$ while passing through $(3,3)$ we will have two sections to the journey.  First, we go from $(0,0)$ to $(3,3)$ in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways, and then from $(3,3)$ to $(7,7)$ in $\binom{8}{4}$ ways, multiplying these together for the total number

Similarly, to go from $(0,0)$ to $(7,7)$ while passing through $(3,3)$ followed by $(4,4)$ requires that we first go to $(3,3)$ and then from there to $(4,4)$ and then to $(7,7)$, etc...

Taking this total and subtracting away from $\binom{14}{7}$ gives us the number of paths who avoided these, giving a final total of:

$$\binom{14}{7}-\binom{6}{3}\binom{8}{4}-\binom{8}{4}\binom{6}{3}+\binom{6}{3}\binom{2}{1}\binom{6}{3} = 1432$$

For what it is worth, $3432 = \binom{14}{7}$ is the total number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(7,7)$ which ignore all other requirements about the missing positions in the graph.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I realized after I posted that I was wrong with the recreation of the problem.   Thank you so much for your explantation!  This makes so much sense.  Have a wonderful day!